# Algorithm - need a hint only

Tags: algorithm

There's a challenge algorithm I'm trying to write. I'm so stuck that I can't even start.
I am not asking for a solution but rather a faint hint of how to approach the problem so that I can come up with a solution myself.

I need to come up with an algorithm that will print a string of length N. That string must contain only 0s and 1s. The number of 0s must be divisible by 3 and the number of 1s must be divisible by 5.

So if I have N = 3 the string is "000"

N = 5, string: "11111"

N = 11, string: "00000011111" (order doesn't matter)

N = 1, string: "-1"

Comment: Perhaps you could reason about it better if you reduced the problem to pure math. "Given some number N, find any non-negative integers `a` and `b` that satisfy the equation `3*a + 5*b = N`."

Comment: Brute-force the number of 0's, compute the number of 1's. That gives you an O(N) algorithm. Or in Kevin's terms: Brute-force a, compute b (or vice versa). That's optimal in the sense that the algorithm will take Omega(N) time anyway because it needs to build up the string

Comment: I have no idea why you posted the code you posted. Since you made no attempt to solve the problem, you may as well just have given us the function signature (taking up much less space in the question), if you deemed that a necessary detail.

Comment: What's the output for N=4?

Comment: for N=4, string: "-1"

Answer (score 3):

Try starting with a string of 0s. Then change 0s to 1s, five at a time, until the conditions are satisfied. This will take no more than 2 changes, so the upper bound is O(1). You can also generate the string after using this method to solve the equation.